# Illustrator CS6 modifies viewBox slighty in SVG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I got SVG graphic from friend saved in Illustrator CS6 (16.0.3). Opened it in the same CS6 version on another machine, forced save as, set SVG export format to the same values as origin and files are not the same:
in original width="1375px" height="602px" viewBox="0 0 1375 602"
after resave width="1375px" height="602px" viewBox="0.0002441 -0.0002441 1375 602"

This "0.0002441" is ratio of 1/4096. I don't know why it adds it.
I know friend is not using any additional settings besides the easy accessible ones.

Illustrator according to this 0.0002441 is changing parameters of all objects in drawing. Precision is set to 7 (max).

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - Please look through [tour] to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. Then look over [ask] and [answer] a question to see what makes a good query here, and how best to frame it. As initially posted, your question is somewhat unclear - I see you specify what you think is an issue / bug with Illustrator and/or your specific use and/or a specific file - I don't see an explicit question, however. Could you edit to refine this?

Comment: What is not understandable in my question? Did You even read this short fragment, or only the last sentence (which is in fact not a question, but statement)? Friend was working on SVG file, and with every save in file there is attribute viewBox="0 0 1375 602". I opened this file in the same CS6 version with the same updates, and settings i could compared and after save viewBox attribute is slightly changed to viewBox="0.0002441 -0.0002441 1375 602". Of course all objects values are adapted to "new" viewbox values so both files are totally different even if no changes were made.

Comment: It seems problem appears only when operation SVG->SVG is executed. When AI->SVG is executed viewBox is saved correctly.